# Creating background task to retrieve PyMongo DB in Flask for Analytics

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I am currently connecting to a remote mongodb to generate a dashboard in Flask. The db connection and load into Pandas occurs on each page request.

```
@app.route("/")

   #connects to db
   #loads to pandas
   #perform analysis and display

@app.route("/recent/")

   #connects to db
   #loads to pandas
   #perform analysis and display
```

Loading the whole dataset into Pandas for each page request is clearly inefficient. The data being loaded does not change frequently (perhaps every 10 minutes or so).

What is the most efficient method / best practice in this situation. Is it possible to define a global function that updates the dataset every x minutes with local functions performing the analysis on the global dataset on each page request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to create background tasks use Celery. To install celery just `pip install celery` (in a virtualenv is ideal as usual). [Here](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask) is complete tutorial for the basics of that. [Here](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-celery-example) is the repo for the project Miguel builds in his blog post. For posterity I'll copy and explain some of the basics here:

```
from flask import Flask
from celery import Celery

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)
```

Obviously just a basic app instance, configured for use with celery. The next hurdle is setting up the "message broker". In this example redis is being used as such.

Here is a script to take care of downloading and running redis for you, *run-redis.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -d redis-stable/src ]; then
    curl -O http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
    tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
    rm redis-stable.tar.gz
fi
cd redis-stable
make
src/redis-server
```

If you follow this linearly you should by now have one terminal running redis, and now you need to open up two more, one to run celery and then one to run the dev server.

```
celery worker -A app.celery --loglevel=info
```

Then:

```
python app.py
```

Assuming `app.run()` is called in *app.py*.

Finally to adapt to your use case you would need create *tasks* in *app.py*.

```
from celery import Celery

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Which get run in the background as:

```
add.delay(4, 4)
```

That's the jist of it. You can set tasks to run at some time in the future. You can also set up tasks to run periodically: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html